# ErrorException in Encrypter.php line 106: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 82 bytes

Tags: laravel, encryption

any some body can help me to fix that error.

this my error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVHFU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

here his my code

```
public function dologin() {

    $input = Input::all();

    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        Alert()->info('Username dan password tidak boleh kosong Panjang Password minimal 6 huruf', 'Info')->persistent('OK');
        return redirect()->route('auth.login');

    } else {
        $user = CoreUser::where('username', $input['username'])->orWhere('user_email', $input['username'])->first();

        if ($user) {

            if($user->user_active != 1){
                Alert()->error('Username sudah tidak aktif', 'Info')->persistent('OK');
                return redirect()->route('auth.login')->withErrors("User tidak aktif");

            }
            if (Hash::check($input['password'], $user->password)) {
                $session = [
                    'username' => $user->username,
                    'password' => $input['password']
                ];
                $remember = true;
                if (Auth::attempt($session, true)) {

                    return redirect()->intended('/');
                } else {
                    // no action
                    dd("failed attempt");
                }
            } else {

                //dd("hash check failed");
                // no action
            }
        }
        Alert()->error('Username dan password tidak sesuai', 'Gagal')->persistent('OK');
        return redirect()->route('auth.login')->withErrors("Invalid Username or Password");
    }
}
```